# Switch to "Native Windows Secure Channel library" from "OpenSSL library" on Windows Git, without reinstalling?

Tags: git, ssh, https, configuration, installation

During the installation of Git on my Windows machine, I selected "Use the OpenSSL library" for HTTPS Transport backend.

I would like to switch to "Native Windows Secure Channel library" for HTTPS Transport.

Is this possible without re-installing git on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by the Git for Windows developer:
https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1274

Answer (score 13):

I found the setting for "schannel" or "openssl" with Git for Windows 2.14.2, 64 bit in file:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\etc\gitconfig
```

Example config for OpenSSL:

```
[http]
sslCAInfo = C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
sslBackend = openssl
```

Example config for Windows native:

```
[http]
sslCAInfo = C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
sslBackend = schannel
```

Answer (score 4):

You can check out [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/git-for-windows/X1WucxvJdGQ) from the Git for Windows maintainer:

> Yes, it is possible, and you can find out how exactly it is done by
>   inspecting the source code for the installer, which is at
>   https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra in the
>   installer/install.iss file (this file is also easily found by a `git grep
>   "Secure Channel"`).
>
> The relevant part is when the installer tests for the GC_WinSSL option to
>   do more interesting stuff than recording the user's choice:

```
if RdbCurlVariant[GC_WinSSL].Checked and (not
    ReplaceFile(BinDir+'curl-winssl\curl.exe',BinDir+'curl.exe') or not
    ReplaceFile(BinDir+'curl-winssl\libcurl-4.dll',BinDir+'libcurl-4.dll'))
then begin
            Log('Line {#__LINE__}: Replacing curl-openssl with curl-winssl failed.');
end;
```

> (See
>   https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/blob/97c8294b584ae4b99059a1194a5eba24ee2ff1ab/installer/install.iss#L1774)
>
> In other words, the installer will simply try to replace the curl.exe and
>   libcurl-4.dll files in \mingw64\bin (or the 32-bit equivalent) by the
>   files in \mingw64\curl-winssl.

Answer (score 4):

This is now offically supported with Git 2.20 (Q4 2018): On platforms with recent cURL library, `http.sslBackend` configuration variable can be used to choose a different SSL backend at runtime.
**The Windows port uses this mechanism to switch between OpenSSL and
Secure Channel while talking over the HTTPS protocol**.

See [commit b67d40a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b67d40adbbaf4f5c4898001bf062a9fd67e43368) (25 Oct 2018), and [commit 21084e8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/21084e84a418e0a6c4da72f632c5cd99386bd64b) (15 Oct 2018) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
See [commit 93aef7c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/93aef7c79beb0bde12f2633423f8edd129eed019) (25 Oct 2018) by [Brendan Forster (`shiftkey`)](https://github.com/shiftkey).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d7b1859](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d7b185973201d7263e84e76044ba3f2b37b1e8a3), 02 Nov 2018)</sup>

> ### `http`: add support for selecting SSL backends at runtime
>
> As of version 7.56.0, curl supports being compiled with multiple SSL
>   backends.
>
> This patch adds the Git side of that feature: by setting `http.sslBackend` to "`openssl`" or "`schannel`", Git for Windows can now choose the SSL
>   backend at runtime.
>
> This comes in handy on Windows because Secure Channel ("schannel") is
>   the native solution, accessing the Windows Credential Store, thereby
>   allowing for enterprise-wide management of certificates.
>   For historical reasons, Git for Windows needs to support OpenSSL still, as it has
>   previously been the only supported SSL backend in Git for Windows for
>   almost a decade.
>
> The patch has been carried in Git for Windows for over a year, and is
>   considered mature.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want to manually edit the config file, you can do it with the command line:

```
git config --global http.sslBackend schannel
```