# Cygwin git with "native Windows Secure Channel library"

Tags: windows, git, cygwin

When I install "Git for Windows" on Windows 10, the installation wizard offers the choice of using either the OpenSSL library or the "native Windows Secure Channel library". (I see this option on my work system, but not on my home laptop, presumably because my home laptop doesn't have that library.)

I'm using the 2.24.1 installer, available [here](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.24.1.windows.2/Git-2.24.1.2-64-bit.exe).

Is there a way to configure Cygwin Git (installed via the [Cygwin installer](https://cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe)) to use the native Windows Secure Channel library?

An ideal solution would let an update to my `.gitconfig` file. A solution that requires building Git from source under Cygwin would also be good (perhaps using a custom-built libcurl?). (Cygwin currently provides git 2.21.0, so I'm using 2.24.1 built from source anyway.)

A closely related question, but not specific to Cygwin:
[Switch to "Native Windows Secure Channel library" from "OpenSSL library" on Windows Git, without reinstalling?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45742607/827263)

**UPDATE** : Something that *didn't* work:

- Build `curl` from [source](https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.67.0.tar.gz) using `./configure --with-schannel`
- Build git-for-windows v2.24.1.windows.2 (cloned from [here](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git)) with
  `make prefix=... CURL_CONFIG=/path/to/curl-config`]
- Add to `$HOME/.gitconfig` :

```
[http]
    sslBackend = schannel
```

The error message on a `git clone https://...` is:

```
fatal: Unsupported SSL backend 'schannel'. Supported SSL backends:
    openssl
```

Comment: I was able to resolve this without using the “native Windows Secure Channel library”, by figuring out how to configure Cygwin git to use ssh.

Comment: I have a similar issue, but git over ssh isn't an option in my environment. Unfortunately, have to use painful ps or git bash for now :(