# error while deploying application to heroku node js from git

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, command-line-interface

```html
PS E:\Node-js-projects\node_jsonwebtoken_login> git add .
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in app.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
PS E:\Node-js-projects\node_jsonwebtoken_login> git commit -m "first commit"
[master 2d2091d] first commit
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)
PS E:\Node-js-projects\node_jsonwebtoken_login> git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 293 bytes | 293.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Deleting 0 files matching .slugignore patterns.
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  12.16.1
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 12.16.1...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 12.16.1...
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.13.4
remote:
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        - node_modules
remote:
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: error:14095126:SSL routines:ssl3_read_n:unexpected eof while reading, errno 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

remote:        Installing node modules
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: error:14095126:SSL
routines:ssl3_read_n:unexpected EOF while reading, errno 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date

I get this error when I deploy a web app to heroku. I use a heroku free dyno. My system is windows 10. I use git to push to heroku. The command is
"git init"
"git add ."
"git commit -m "first commit"
"Heroku create app name"
"git push heroku master"

Everything goes fine until the line of "remote: Installing node modules".
This is not the first time I am deploying this app, previous deploys were all fine. But this deploy gets failed.

```html
@NickShebanov same problem started again. but now it is in early stage. `git add .
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in app.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
PS E:\Node-js-projects\node_jsonwebtoken_login> git commit -m "first commit"
[master 6d08b27] first commit
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)
PS E:\Node-js-projects\node_jsonwebtoken_login> git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 24, done.
Counting objects: 100% (24/24), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
Writing objects: 100% (20/20), 5.90 MiB | 3.48 MiB/s, done.
Total 20 (delta 12), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: error:14095126:SSL routines:ssl3_read_n:unexpected eof while reading, errno 10035
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date`
```

Comment: Did I get it right that you get this error when doing `git push`? If so, could you update the question with the command, and some details about your environment? What dynos are you on, what is the version of `heroku-toolbelt` and node, and what are the buildpacks you use? The full log could shed a bit more light too.

Comment: @NickShebanov I have updated the question. This is my first question on StackOverflow, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks for the edits! Could you also share your package.json? It looks like the error might be related to a bug in certain versions of openssl (https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/11381)

Comment: yes sure. I have made a copy of this file and uploaded it through another Heroku account. but that works perfectly. Don't know what is wrong with this.

Comment: @NickShebanov Now it worked perfectly because I have uninstalled some unused packages from this project. But can you please explain what exactly caused that problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @NickShebanov same problem started again. but there is a difference in the stage. Edited the question with a new problem.

Comment: It looks like it has nothing to do with heroku per se, and is a git error. Could you share your git version? Would it help if you update git to the most recent version? Also, would this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45742607/switch-to-native-windows-secure-channel-library-from-openssl-library-on-wind?

Comment: My git version is 2.26.0.1. I am using windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

Try these :-

1. Increase git buffer by `git config http.postBuffer 524288000`
2. Disable SSL validation on git! through: `git config http.sslVerify false` => (Don't forget IF YOU DIDN'T GET ANSWER from this, "ROLL IT BACK!")

Comment: I didn't get the answer. Still facing the same problem.