# fatal: Could not read from remote repository when i try to clone repository

Tags: git, git-clone

I am trying to clone a repository and changed the https for SSH and the same error.

```
PS C:\Git_e_GitHub\1_primeiro_repo> git clone https://github.com/....../......git
Cloning into 'curso_git_1'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/......../...........git/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

PS C:\Git_e_GitHub\1_primeiro_repo> git clone git@github.com:......./.........git
Cloning into 'curso_git_1'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Please help me

Comment: have you tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509293/git-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-repository ?

Answer (score 0):

I was talking to a friend whos has the same problem and he told do try this command:

git config --global http.sslbackend schannel

And then:

git clone https://github.com/fbergami57/*********.git

It worked

Thanks everybody for the helping

Answer (score 0):

The `git config --global http.sslbackend schannel` would work on Windows because, as explained in Git 2.20 (Q4 2018), on platforms with recent cURL library, `http.sslBackend` configuration variable can be used to choose a different SSL backend at runtime.

The Windows port uses this mechanism to switch between OpenSSL and Secure Channel while talking over the HTTPS protocol.

I detailed it in "[Switch to "Native Windows Secure Channel library" from "OpenSSL library" on Windows Git, without reinstalling?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53137619/6309)"